# how to place custom text in customer form adminhtml

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer, adminhtml

I want to place custom text in 'adminhtml_customer_edit' before the 'personal Information' section. 
[image]

For this i have wrote
**etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <VLC_DynamicsNAV>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </VLC_DynamicsNAV>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <dynamicsnav>
                <class>VLC_DynamicsNAV_Block</class>
            </dynamicsnav>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <dynamicsnav>
                    <file>dynamicsnav.xml</file>
                </dynamicsnav>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**VLC_DynamicsNAV.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <VLC_DynamicsNAV>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </VLC_DynamicsNAV>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**adminhtml\default\default\layout\dynamicsnav.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout>
        <adminhtml_customer_edit>
            <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
                <block type="dynamicsnav/customerbtn" name="customer.nav.button"
                       template="dynamicsnav/customer.phtml"
                       before="customer_edit_tab_view"/>
            </reference>
        </adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

and **VLC\DynamicsNAV\Block\adminhtml\customerbtn.php**

```
<?php
class VLC_DynamicsNAV_Block_adminhtml_customerbtn extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{    
}
```

**app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\dynamicsnav\customer.phtml**

```
<h1>WELCOME TO THE NEW WORLD</H1>
```

How to place custom text in customer edit card form in the customer view section before the **Personal Information** group

Comment: You already did it. What more do you need?

Comment: @fschmengler i have placed text using developer tools to show what i need. In magento after placing all the above code its not showing custom text

Answer (score 0):

1. The file name `VLC\DynamicsNAV\Block\adminhtml\customerbtn.php` should be `VLC\DynamicsNAV\Block\Adminhtml\Customerbtn.php`
2. `customer_edit_tabs` is the wrong parent, it's a tab container, not the tab itself. Also it does not render added children automatically. The tab itself is the block `customer_edit_tab_view`
3. Unfortunately, `customer_edit_tab_view` renders all children, but at the bottom (see last line in the template), so you will need to copy the template and modify it so that your new block is rendered before the `<h4>` element.

#### layout\dynamicsnav.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout>
        <adminhtml_customer_edit>
            <reference name="customer_edit_tab_view">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>dynamicsnav/customer_view.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>

            <block type="dynamicsnav/customerbtn" name="customer.nav.button"
                   template="dynamicsnav/customer.phtml" />
        </adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

Note that I added the block outside the parent so that it will not be rendered by `getChildHtml()` at the bottom.

#### template/dynamicsnav/customer_view.phtml

```
<div class="entry-edit">

    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('customer.nav.button')->toHtml(); ?>

    <div class="entry-edit-head"><h4 class="icon-head head-customer-view"><?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->__('Personal Information') ?></h4></div>
```

Comment: in the point 3, we need to copy the template and modify, If we upgrade we might lost upgrade version content here. I dont want to disturb magento core, Just i want to place text before the **Account Information**

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot simply add content *in the middle of a template* without modifying the template. However you could use the core_block_abstract_tohtml_after event to "inject" content.

Comment: Please clarify that 'adminhtml/default/default/' our customized layout & template files will be overridden by magento on upgradation?. For eg: layout - 'adminhtml\default\default\layout\dynamicsnav.xml', template - 'template/dynamicsnav/customer_view.phtml'

Comment: No, they won't be overwritten on update because you don't change the core template but copy it and then use this copy.